# Error occurred while installing dotnetnuke

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-settings

I have a problem installing DotNetNuke 7. I configured the ISS, the sql Server database and the setup started perfectly. But then it showed me this error:

**13% ERROR occured - Step Failed - File Deletion Check**

I have not all adminstrator rights on this pc, can that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to configure the user permissions on the FOLDERS for DNN. I'm not sure if you not being an administrator will cause a problem, probably so.

What OS are you installing DNN on? Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving full security access IIS_USRS user.